# import 'package:http/http.dart'; not available after install dependency with latest version

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new for Flutter, 
I am trying to call API by using

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
```

But this package does not appear after installed dependency as

```
http: ^0.12.0+1
```

in "pubspec.yaml" file with the running of "package get" command.

I am using Flutter in Android Studio.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your IDE?

Comment: yes, after restart also I facing same issues.

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: "But this package does not appear" where do you expect it to appear?

Comment: Maybe are you only missing as http? `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`

Comment: import 'package:http/http.dart';  shows red color. How can I able to call API when package not import.

Comment: So that was happening to me too. See my answer. Let us know if this solves, otherwise we will try to search another reason. Once I got rid of the lint error I never got it again. Btw, as you can read I wan able to use the package even with the error, so if you still get the error try to use it anyway. Let me know.

Comment: I got this error when i run the application as you said, "Your application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could not be established.That library is in a package that is not known. Maybe you forgot to mention it in your pubspec.yaml file?"   i kept this "http: '^0.12.0+1'"version in  pubspec.yaml

Still i cannot run the application.

Comment: Can you post your entire pubspec.yaml file? And the listing of .pub_cache folder? Can you also post your main.dart file?

Comment: does `flutter packages get` cause any errors? Does the `.packages` in your project directory exist and contain an entry for the `http` package.

Comment: No, I did not get any error when i run the package

Comment: This is the coding in  pubspec.yaml  name: request
description: A new Flutter application.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: '^0.1.2'
http: '^0.12.0+1'


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

Comment: In main.dart i use this package.,               import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Comment: I dont know mistake in this coding.

Comment: anyone know the solution for these issues, is any issues in this coding.

Comment: did you get any solution? I am facing the same problem. please share it with me.

Comment: Not familiar with android studio, but with flutter you need to say 'flutter pub get' to update the dependencies. (I'm using IntelIJ IDEA, it  asks about this) see https://pub.dev/packages/http/install

Answer (score 0):

if you import you package like that

```
import 'package:http/http.dart'
```

all you need to do is

```
Response response;
response = await get('you link here');
```

but you can rename the package and use

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

and you can use it like that :

```
http.Response response;
    response = await http.get('you link here');
```

Comment: Above package not appear when i write the coding.

Comment: import 'package:http/http.dart'; shows red color. How can I able to call API when package not import.